# silexでcontrollerを作成してファイルを置く場合にどこのフォルダに設置するべきですか？

Tags: php, silex

/silex/web/index.phpが表示されるまでできましたが、この先、controller,view,modelの設置ノ仕方がわかりません。
チュートリアルをみましたが、一番初期の設置、書き方がのっていないように思えるのでアドバイスください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

特にルールはありません。

Silexの場合、ここに置いたコントローラが自動的に読み込まれるとか、ビューの名前はあるフォルダからの相対パスで指定するとか、そういったことはありません。ですから好きな場所に好きなものを置いて構いません。ディレクトリを分けないことも可能です。

ファイルの中身についても決まりはありませんから、好きなように書いて、それを読み込むコードを自分で書くことになります。